# Simplify code with loop

Tags: vba, loops

Hi I'm pretty new at the vba so please don't shoot my code :-).
I have a set of repaeting code's. I woukld like to simplify this code by using the code name with an increasing number. I can't get it to run. Can someone help me a bit on the road to get this going.
Below what I'm trying.
The second block is a part of the code now (it's 40 blocks of the same code only increasing the number)

```
Sub sheet41()
Dim i As Integer
Dim chkname As Integer
chkname = "SheetCheckBox" & i
i = 1
Do
  i = i + 1
  If chkname.Visible = False Then Exit Sub
  If chkname.value = True Then
    Sheets("Item_" & i).Select
    Call Finalize
  End If
Loop Until i = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
End Sub
```

This is the old code:

```
Sub Sheet1()
If SheetCheckBox1.Visible = False Then Exit Sub
If SheetCheckBox1.value = True Then
  Sheets("Item_1").Select
  Call Finalize
End If
End Sub

Sub Sheet2()
If SheetCheckBox2.Visible = False Then Exit Sub
If SheetCheckBox2.value = True Then
  Sheets("Item_2").Select
  Call Finalize
End If
End Sub

Sub Sheet3()
If SheetCheckBox3.Visible = False Then Exit Sub
If SheetCheckBox3.value = True Then
  Sheets("Item_3").Select
  Call Finalize
End If
End Sub
```

As you can see this should be possible to clean I asume.

Comment: `chkname` is just a string, you need to get the actual control it refers to - why have you defined chkname as an Integer..?

Comment: @VladNeacsu code review is for working code, which this certainly isn't

Comment: Also, the first sheet you process is Sheet2, as you increment i at the start of the loop and it's initial value is 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the checkboxes on the Sheet are ActiveX Controls, you can use this to access the checkboxes:

```
Sheets("sheet1").OLEObjects("chkTest").Object
```

if you want to change the value of a checkbox, use it like this:

```
    Sheets("sheet1").OLEObjects("chkTest").Object.Value = True
```

now replace `"sheet1"` with your actual sheet name and change the `"chkTest"` to your string `chkname`

So your complete code should be like this:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim sheetname As String
Dim chkname As String

sheetname = "YOUR SHEETNAME HERE"

For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count Step 1

    chkname = "SheetCheckBox" & i

    If Sheets(sheetname).OLEObjects(chkname).Object.Visible = False Then Exit Sub

    If Sheets(sheetname).OLEObjects(chkname).Object.Value = True Then

        Sheets("Item_" & i).Select
        Call Finalize
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: The checkboxes are running on a userform. This code looks like what I'm looking for. Except the sheetname will be raised with each marked checkbox automatically. This in the range "Item_1" "Item_2" etc like the checkboxes.

Comment: If the checkboxes are on a userform, you should be able to replace the `Sheets(sheetname)` with your Formname. It was just in case you are using the same worksheet over and over again

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.  If `finalize` isn't called on a worksheet then the reason why is printed to the Immediate Window.

[image]

```
Sub ProcessWorkSheets()

    Dim check As MSForms.CHECKBOX
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count

        On Error Resume Next
        Set check = Worksheets(i).OLEObjects("SheetCheckBox" & i).Object
        On Error GoTo 0
        If check Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print Worksheets(i).Name; " - Checkbox not found"
        Else
            If check.Visible And check.Value Then
                Worksheets(i).Select
                Call Finalize
            Else
                Debug.Print Worksheets(i).Name; " - Checkbox", "Visible", check.Visible, "Value:", check.Value
            End If
        End If

        Set check = Nothing
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks I will try if I can use this code. Basically I don't need to get a box printed but I need the routine to run all possible options until the max sheet number which can be 40. (With more I have to add them but that's no problem). The code runs on a userform by the way.